# Free ERM modelling software for Mac

Tags: macos, software-rec

I'm searching a free software to create [entity relationship modells](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-relationship_model) (for Mac OSX 10.6+).

#### Needed functions (mandatory):

- draw model
- add descriptions to relations

#### Needed functions (optional):

- Chen's notation for entity-relationship modeling

  [image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Oracle [SQL Data Modeler](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/datamodeler/downloads/index.html)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The SQL Data Modeler is a pretty nice and handy tool. But I need the possiblity to add a description to relations and I was not able to find that feature using the software. (I missed that needed feature in my first question so I've made some additions)

Comment: @hkda150 Sorry I'm not aware of any other application which support the feature

Answer (score 1):

### [MySQL Workbench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/)

Allows you to model SQL in an ER-like fashion. There's a standard community version, and a commercial version, which have [a different feature set](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/features.html).

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure if it fulfills your needed functionality.